# Accessing values of promises in an array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create an array from http requests that holds a name property and two promises: one as an array and the other as an object. I'm able to get the info I need using this approach but I'm not able to access it to display it in the scope of the html. For instance, when I log out the array, "people" I get an array of objects (looking like: [Object, Object, Object]) and I have to expand a bunch of things to see the actual values of each object so that "person.skills" would really have to be "person.skills.$$state.value". Also, on the page, {{person.name}} will show up but the other two are just empty objects that look like this: {}. So how can I access the values of the promises so that I can just use {{person.skills}} to show the array?

**js**

```
var getPeople = function() {
            var named = $q.defer();
            $http.get('/getnames').success(function (response) {
                named.resolve(response);
            });
            return named.promise;
        };


        getPeople().then(function(namesRes) {
            var people = [];
            names = namesRes;
            names.forEach(function(index){
                var name = index;
                var count = $q.defer();
                var skills = $q.defer();
                var urls = '/getskillsbyname/' + name;
                var urlc = '/getcountbyname/' + name;
                $http.get(urls).success(function (response) {
                    skills.resolve(response);
                });
                $http.get(urlc).success(function (response) {
                    count.resolve(response);
                });
                people.push({name:name, skills:skills.promise, count:count.promise});
            });
            return people;
        }).then(function(people) {
            console.log(people);
            $scope.people = people;
        });
```

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat="person in people">
                <p>{{person.name}}</p>
                <p>{{person.skills}}</p>
                <p>{{person.count}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are using a classic anti-pattern. `$http` returns a promise. See: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns

Comment: I realize I didn't take the most efficient approach but is it possible to make this existing code work? I just want to make it work before I restructure it.

Comment: @muninn9 You aren't really going to get it to work in this format, as is. The simple reason is that you're expecting promises to be magical, and turn into their value. That's not how they work. A promise lets you listen for when the value does (or doesn't) arrive.  The solution requires more code, because you have to listen for each promise's completion to grab the value from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method not returning promise correctly, you need to use `$q` for waiting till all the inner promises get completed.

I have implemented your code by maintaining grand promise variable in the `forEach` loop, whenever asking `skills` and `couts` call are made, it put that call inside `$q.all` and `$q.all` promise is moved to `grandPromiseArray`.

```
var getPeople = function() {
    return $http.get('/getnames');
};

getPeople().then(function(response) {
  var people = [];
  names = response.data;
  grandPromiseArray = [];
  names.forEach(function(index) {
    var name = index, count = $q.defer(), skills = [],
        urls = '/getskillsbyname/' + name, urlc = '/getcountbyname/' + name;
    grandPromiseArray.push(
      $q.all([$http.get(urls), $http.get(urlc)])
      .then(function(response) {
        people.push({
          name: name,
          skills: response[0].data, //response[0] value returned by 1st promise
          count: response[1].data //response[1] value returned by 2nd promise
        });

      })
    );

  });
  return $q.all(grandPromiseArray).then(function() {
    return people
  });
})
.then(function(people) {
  console.log(people);
  $scope.people = people;
});
```

Comment: Whew, okay, that makes a lot more sense! I cannot thank everyone enough for steering me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Example for a valid promise chain:

```
function getSomeData(){
   var defer = $q.defer();

   $http.get(urls).success(function (response) {
      defer.resolve(response);
   });

   return defer.promise;
}
```

And then you can access the promise data like:

```
getSomeData().then(function(data){
   console.log(data); // This is the response of the $http request
});
```

Organize your requests in functions and it looks much cleaner.

$http also returns promise by default, but I recommend to create a service/factory, which doing your requests, then you need the defer.

```
$http.get(urls).then(function(data){

});
```

Comment: I see people create deferred objects whose promises get resolved when the `$http` promise resolves all the time, but I don't understand the purpose...  Why not just `return $http.get(urls);`?

Comment: Updated. If you managed your code into some custom services/factories and chaining the whole thing, you need to defer the promise to chain it correctly. In your case, $http.get(urls).then(function(data){}); would be enough, but you have to care about timing. inside the 'then' is a other time-of-execution as the code after the $http calls, but I think you know that.

Comment: @mgilson What you are suggesting is indeed [considered an anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns)

Comment: @CodeNashor you don't have to defer at all in your example. You can just return the `$http.get( )`. If you need to chain more together, after the get, you still don't need to defer...  ...just keep chaining `.then` and return the whole chain.

Answer (score 1):

A Promise isn't going to automatically allow you to display your results in Angular.

A Promise is an object, which lets you chain async operations together, by passing in functions which are eventually fired and passed the value.

You can't ask for `myPromise.value` and expect it to be there, because it's an async process which might take 20ms, 2mins, or might just never come back at all.

In terms of how this is structured, it might be much cleaner and easier to reason about if you broke the data-fetching parts out into a service, and just injected the service into the controller.

I'm not sure which version of Angular you've been working with, but I'm hoping its at least 1.2.
Also, my example is using the native Promise constructor, but I'm sure Angular's version of $q now has everything that's needed, if you aren't using a promise polyfill.

```
function PersonService (http) {
  function getResponseData (response) { return response.data; }
  function getURL (url) { return http.get(url).then(getResponseData); }

  function makePerson (personData) {
    return {
      name: personData[0],
      skills: personData[1],
      count: personData[2]
    };
  }

  var personService = {
    getNames: function () { return getURL("/names/"); },
    getSkills: function (name) { return getURL("/getskillsbyname/" + name); },
    getCounts: function (name) { return getURL("/getcountsbyname/" + name); },
    loadPerson: function (name) {
      return Promise.all([
        Promise.resolve(name),
        personService.getSkills(name),
        personService.getCount(name)
      ]).then(makePerson);
    },
    loadPeople: function (names) {
      return Promise.all(names.map(personService.loadPerson));
    }
  };

  return personService;
}
```

Here's what my person service might look like.
I've written a couple of super-small helper functions that keep getting reused.
Then I've made the service all about getting either people or details about people.
I'm using `Promise.all`, and passing it an array of promises. When every promise in the array is complete, it returns an array of all of the data returned by the promises. `Promise.resolve` is used in one spot. It basically returns a promise which succeeds automatically, with the value it was given. That makes it really useful, when you need a promise to start a chain, but you don't have to do anything special, aside from returning a value you already have.
My assumption is both that `q` now names its methods the same way the spec does, and that Angular's implementation of `$q` follows the spec as well.

```
function MyController (personService) {
  var controller = this;
  controller.people = [];
  controller.error = false;
  init();

  function setPeople (people) {
    controller.people = people || [];
  }

  function handleError (err) {
    setPeople([]);
    controller.error = true;
  }

  function init () {
    return personService.getNames()
      .then(personService.loadPeople)
      .then(setPeople)
      .catch(handleError);
  }
}
```

My controller now gets really, really simple. It's using the service to get names, and load people, and then it sets them, and it's ready to go.  If there was an error, I handle it in whatever way makes sense.

Handling the injection of this stuff is pretty quick and easy:

```
angular.module("myExample")
.service("PersonService", ["$http", PersonService])
.controller("MyController", ["PersonService", MyController]);
```

Using this on the page is now painless, as well:

```
<div ng-controller="MyController as widget">
  <ul ng-hide="widget.people.length == 0">
    <li ng-repeat="person in widget.people">
      <person-details person="person"></person-details>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div ng-show="widget.error">Sorry, there was an error with your search.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, great answer. I might go this route.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could probably use `$q.all` to construct your people:

```
var p = $q.all({
  name: $q.when(name),
  skills: $http.get(urls),
  count: $http.get(urlc)
});

p.then(function(person) {
  people.push(person);
});
```

`$q.all` will construct a new promise that gets resolved when all of the input promises resolve.  Since we input a map, `$q.all` will resolve with a map that has the same keys.  The values are the resolutions of the corresponding promises.  In this case, that's a person so we can then just push it into the people array directly.

This is a slightly naive implementation.  Since the calls are asynchronous, there is no guarantee that the order of names will be preserved in people -- but it shouldn't be too hard for you to fix that if it is important.

Comment: FWIW, depending on how many requests you're spawning, it might be worth making backend-handlers to deal with these things in a single request.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of all the promises for the counts and skills. Have broken those requests up into their own functions for readability

Also `then()` of `$http` returns a promise object that has a property `data`

```
var getPeople = function() {    
  return $http.get('/getnames').then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  });    
};


getPeople().then(function(people) {
  var promises = [];

  people.forEach(function(person) {
    // push new requests to promise array
    promises.push(getSkills(person));
    promises.push(getCount(person))

  });
  // when all promises resolved return `people`
  return $q.all(promises).then(function() {
     // return `people` to next `then()`
    return people;
  });
}).then(function(people) {
  console.log(people);
  $scope.people = people;

}).catch(function(){
   // do something if anything gets rejected
});

function getCount(person) {
  var urlc = '/getcountbyname/' + person.name;    
  return $http.get(urlc).then(function(response) {
    person.count = response.data
  });

}

function getSkills(person) {
  var urls = '/getskillsbyname/' + person.name;
  return $http.get(urls).then(function(response) {
    person.skills = response.data
  });

}
```